# Add data-attribute to appended object src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append a link to multiple list-items that passes the data-attribute to the end of the URL. However I don't understand how to make the variable "storyId" hold a different value for each instance of .Story

```
<div id="InnerPage">
  <ol>
    <li class="Story" data-id="35213">Text for Link 1 </li>
    <li class="Story" data-id="35204">Text for Link 2 </li>
  </ol>
</div>

<script>
  var storyId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
  var sidebarURL = "'index.html?storyid=' + storyId"
  var newA = document.createElement('a');
  newA.setAttribute('href',sidebarURL);
  newA.innerHTML = "Split View";

  $('.Story').append([newA]);
</script>
```

Should result in:

```
<div id="InnerPage">
  <ol>
    <li class="Story" data-id="35213">Text for Link 1 <a href="index.html?storyid=35213">Split View</a></li>
    <li class="Story" data-id="35204">Text for Link 2 <a href="index.html?storyid=35204">Split View</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s3wtsxw5/

Comment: whats' the `this` in your script? a bare `this` like that in JS outside of an object/function is very unusual. it could even be referring the `<script>` DOM object, not any of your `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#InnerPage ol li").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var link = "index.html?storyid=" + id;
    $(this).append("<a href='" + link + "'>Split View</a>");
});
```

Comment: @NathanGathright -- Be sure to mark the answer if it did what ya needed.